# OpenApi seperating definition by tags

Tags: json, swagger, openapi

I want to seperate some funtion in OpenAPI from the main content. I thougth about to give each function a specific tag (secret, maincontent) and let run a programm over my JSON-File to seperate it into 2 API-Documentation. Has anybody got some experience with seperating or spliting API's like that?

Comment: Releated: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/433

Comment: thank you. i think we can close this question.